# Whats the logical difference between two numbers being both even, versus two numbers having same parity?

Tags: logic

Whats the logical difference between two numbers being both even, versus two numbers having same parity?
I'm trying to find the negation of these statements...

Comment: "In mathematics, [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)) is the property of an integer of whether it is even or odd. "

Comment: Two odd numbers have the same parity but they are not even.

Comment: The negation of "a and b are both even" will be "either a is not even or b is not even".

Comment: But this is not the same as "not having the same parity", because "either a is not even or b is not even" is true also when a is odd and b is odd :-)

Comment: Two integers have the same parity iff their difference is even.